# Ionic Routing and Template not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic and Angular UI also. I am trying to use templates to load my first page in my Ionic app. My folder structure is as following.

[image: Folder Structure]

I want to use my `index.html` as the container for all my templates. I am trying to use `list.html` as the template the loads into the `index.html` when my app first loads. I have tried the following code and I am stuck.

```
.config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){

  $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
      url: '/',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'index.html'
    })
    .state('index.list', {
      url: '/list',
      views: {
        'list-index' : {
          templateUrl: 'list.html',
          controller: 'ListCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/list');
})
```

My `index.html` has nothing but an 
`<ion-nav-view name='list-index'></ion-nav-view>` inside the body tag.

The `list.html` has some code that loads a list by fetching some JSON content using conotroller `ListCtrl`.

**The app loads up blank.**

I need to be pointed in the right direction. I think that I am too close to the correct solution. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Adding code for `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-nav-view name='list-index'></ion-nav-view>

  </body>
</html>
```

Link to `app.js` - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPVJao

Comment: Do u have any javascript errors ?, you can check with by running the app `ionic serve` and checking the developer tools in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Can you please describe your ionic app directory structure.

It shall be :

```
PROJECT
 - hooks
 - platforms
 - www
   - js <=== this dir includes all your js in ionic structure. 
   - templates/ <== this is a dir that includes all html templates in ionic structure
   - index.html <== THIS IS THE STARTING POINT OF YOUR PROJECT, CONTAINING angularJS script and ng-app for exemple
```

into your template directory, you can have "index.html & list.html"

but this shall update your routing as :

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
      url: '/',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/index.html'
    })
    .state('index.list', {
      url: '/list',
      views: {
        'list-index' : {
          templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
          controller: 'ListCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

if you keep your templateURl as  `templateUrl: 'index.html'` then, I assume that you 'll be in conflict with your main index.html .... bad idea.

Comment: Yes, I want my main file, index.html as the parent container. I do not have a folder called templates, so I have both the files inside the folder www. My app.js is in js folder.

Comment: if you dont have a templates folder, then why would you give templateUrl as 'templates/list'.

Comment: I did not, please check the code I posted on the question. It is necessary to have a folder called templates?

Comment: Added the folder structure.

Comment: Added the code. I also checked your updated answer. I don't understand why is it mandatory to have a `templates` folder. Can't we make this work without creating a folder?

Comment: you can make it work without the folder. It is just cleaner to have a folder and separate your js / html / css into a directory structure.

Comment: please add the FULL index.html

Comment: I understand that it is good to have  a cleaner structure. I will create a `templates` folder, may be after I figure out what is wrong with my app right now.

Comment: add the full app.js file plz. your index.html seems ok

Comment: I have already added the major part of `app.js` in the question. Apart from that I just have a controller that gets the data from Parse.com and displays it in the list. It was all working fine as long as I had all the code in one file.

Comment: add it all please. It seems that you do not start properly your angular app

Comment: Added the link to codepen that has code of the `app.js` file.